# Mark success programmatically not making the downstream tasks to run

Tags: airflow

DAG FLOW :

A >> B >> C >> D

Currently When Task C is failed , Task D will be in upstream_failed state. In this DAG run if I manually Mark Success on Task C , TASK D will be triggered automatically.

When I want to program this activity(marking success of a task using code ti.set_state('success') it is marking the Task C success but TASK D is still in upstream_failed status.

Answer (score 3):

Channing state won't be enough. You need to change state and rerun downstream (that's what happens when you change state in UI and click clear). Take a look at [_mark_task_instance_state](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1220c1a7a9698cdb15289d7066b29c209aaba6aa/airflow/www/views.py#L2340-L2349) and [_clear_dag_tis](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1220c1a7a9698cdb15289d7066b29c209aaba6aa/airflow/www/views.py#L1984). Probably running [dag.clear](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1220c1a7a9698cdb15289d7066b29c209aaba6aa/airflow/models/dag.py#L1762) after changing TI instance will be enough.

Comment: @ThomaszUrbaszek tried dag.clear but it clears all tasks and not just the intended task i.e it cleared task A onwards and not just task D even if I mention task_id as D